# SonarQube - How to use sonarRunner tasks / sonar.properties file globally with gradle wrapper for all projects

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, sonarqube, code-coverage

I am implementing sonarQube in one of my project.The source code is in java and all build files are written in gradle 2.3.My project is having 8 modules under same 
repository and I am using the gradle wrapper while building the module.I checked in gradle wrapper for each module with module source code.while I trigger the build it checkout the gradle version(mentioned in wrapper properties file) from the artifactoryand use gradlew to build the artifact.

Below is mentioned in the wrapper properties files

```
Tue Mar 17 10:20:49 EDT 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://xyx.n.tson.com\:9000/artifactory/ext-release-local/org/gradle/gradle/2.3/gradle-2.3-bin.zip
```

while it checkout it creates a wrapper/dist in workspace in  below manner(Using Jenkins)

```
wrapper/dists/gradle-2.3-bin/7gkccujig8oqm5bun82efob8m7/gradle-2.3/init.d/
```

Now I want to implement the sonar and for that I need to create global sonar.properties file or better add a section for **sonarRunner** Gradle task (containing all the *sonar.xx.xx* properties) where I can keep all the configuration and use it globally . I don't want to write the properties for each module.Can someone tell me if I am using the gradle wrapper where I can keep this property file and make it global for all modules instead of changing or creating the property file for each module.

Comment: As officially announced by the Gradleware team (see https://twitter.com/gradle/status/613530568655966208), only the Gradle SonarQube plugin should be used to launch some SonarQube analysis from Gradle: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Gradle

Answer (score 0):

I would put this file somewhere near your rootproject instead of having it with the wrapper itself. I would put it under `$rootproject/gradle/sonar/sonar.properties)`

from your build script you can reference this file via

```
rootproject.file("gradle/sonar/sonar.properties")
```

cheers,

René

Comment: Will this work, even if I run "sonarRunner" Gradle task? I assume this will work if someone runs sonar-runner (in the project's workspace) from command line (or using Execute Shell in Jenkins). I think what he's trying to ask is, how can he create GRADLE_HOME/init.d/a-global.gradle file where he can put his sonarRunner { ... } settings/with variables etc and it can be available to each module/project's build scope. How can this be done, when he's using gradlew (wrapper). Basically, then we don't have to check-in sonar.properties in each individual project or anywhere even in the root project.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a non intrusive way to activate sonarqube plugin on your project (ie without doing a modification of build.gradle) then I have no idea of how to do that.

But if you want a way to pass properties configured in global Jenkins configuration (like server URL and credentials) to your build, then you should follow this ticket as this is a known limitation:
http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJNKNS-217